# Make error when compiling c++ program using pgi fortran subroutines

Tags: c++, fortran, lapack, blas

I'm trying to couple the fortran program to c++ based manager program.

In this regard, I wanted to make a new c++ program consisting of the subroutines of existing fortran program and simple c++ script.

To compile the new program, I used the CMakeLists.txt and then there were compile errors. I added mpic++, mpicc and mpif90 compilers on CMakeLists.txt.

Error was shown as follows:

```
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `__pgi_dev_cublasddot_hhpm'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `pgf90_dev_mod_dealloc03_i8'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `pgf90_dev_symhandle_copyout'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparseSetMatFillMode'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `__pgi_dev_cublassasum_hhpm'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `pgf90_dev_alloc04_i8'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `pgf90_dev_copyin'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudamemcpyr8in_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cublasSetStream_v2'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparsedcsrsv_solve_sethpm_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `__pgi_uacc_get_deviceptr_offset'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparseSetMatType'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudamemcpyr8_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `__pgi_uacc_dataexitstart2'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparseDestroyMatDescr'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudaeventsynchronize_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudadevicesetcacheconfig_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudagetdeviceproperties_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cusparsedcsrmv_sethpm_'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `pgf90_dev_memset4v'
libWorker.so: undefined reference to `cudastreamcreatei8_'
...
```

The fortran program used lapack and blas libraries. Therefore, I tried to add libraries by cmake but it seems to be failed.

How can I resolve this problem?

I used find_package but the lapack was not found with cmake message of "Could NOT find LAPACK".

But the fortran program was compiled succefully with mpif90 program when it was compiled as a fortran program.

The followings are what I tried to add libraries

```
find_package(BLAS)
find_package(LAPACK)
if (LAPACK_FOUND)
   set (LAPACK_LIB_DIR  ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
endif()

if (BLAS_FOUND)
   set (BLAS_LIB_DIR ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
endif()

...

target_link_libraries (
       <fortran program name>
       <c++ program name>
       ${LAPACK_LIB_DIR}
       ${BLAS_LIB_DIR}
)
```

Comment: *"Therefore, I tried to add libraries by cmake but it seems to be failed."* How did you try? How exactly does it seem? Which compilers are behind the mpicc mpic++ and mpif90 wrappers? How roes your CMakeLists.txt look like? See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You need to specify `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to location of the library installation when find_package fails. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the body of the question. I will try CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH